# Automatically insert curly braces around case statement

Tags: eclipse, formatting

In Eclipse, how can I automatically place curly braces around `case` statements?

Example:

```
case 1:
    break;
```

should become

```
case 1: {
    break;
}
```

I've looked at the formatter and the clean-up tools and there doesn't seem to be an option to do this. Preferably this should be done when I use the formatter *or* when I use the **"Insert missing case statements"** quick-fix. Plugins are acceptable if there is no native way in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this that I've found is sub-optimal and quite tedious. You can do this by adding a new editor template by navigating through the menus: `Window > Java > Editor > Templates` then pressing `New...` and use this as the pattern:

```
case ${value}: {
    ${cursor}
    break;
}
```

You can now insert this wherever in your code by simply typing "case" and then pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to bring up templace proposals and then selecting "case" (should be at the top).